# Search friends FQL is slow

Tags: ajax, facebook, facebook-fql

I am allowing the user to search their facebook friends with an ajax request with the keyup javascript function.

The ajax request calls a php action that uses the fql to search through a users friends and output 10 of the friends. 
This ajax request takes on average 5 seconds so is not quick enough for someone typing, is there any way to make my code quicker or make it more efficient?

```
$params = array("method"=> "fql.query", "query"=> "SELECT uid, name, pic FROM user WHERE strpos(lower(first_name), '$data') >= 0 AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) ORDER BY first_name LIMIT 10 ", "callback"=> "");

$friends  =  $facebook->api($params);
$this->view->friends = $friends;
```

where $data holds the name to search for.
I then output this in my view in html format. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a good idea to make a new request each time the user adds a character. You should load your friends all at once with the page itself. Or better, you can do that transparently using AJAX just after the page entirely loaded.

You will then avoid any slow requests because you already got the user's friends. The result with be immediate. To do so, I advice you to use the [jQuery Autocomplete plugin](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).